# Is there an equivalent of Org-mode's b_ignoreheading for non-beamer documents?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When using Org-mode to create [beamer presentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Beamer-class-export.html#Beamer-class-export) it is possible to set the [property](http://orgmode.org/manual/Properties-and-Columns.html#Properties-and-Columns) of a heading such that the exported heading is not shown but only its contents. For instance, the following

```
#+title: Test

#+options: toc:nil
#+latex_class: beamer
#+startup: beamer

#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2

* Ignored heading                                           :B_ignoreheading:
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
:END:
Text
```

Result in a frame with "Text" only and no heading. Is this kind of functionality available for non-beamer documents? That is, is it possible to tell Org-mode to not export a heading but only its contents? For instance, would it be possible to make Org-mode export the following

```
#+title: Test

* Ignored heading
Text
```

without exporting the heading "Ignored heading" but only "Text"?

If I export

```
#+title: Test

* 
Text
```

(note the space after `*`) to LaTeX I get the following (I only included the relevant part):

```lisp
\section{}

Text
```

But this is not what I want. I want the heading to be completely ignored in the export so that I would get the following (again I only include the relevant part):

```lisp
Text
```

Comment: It's not an answer to what you want, but you should be able to just use a heading asterisk and a blank space so that the there is no title to the heading, like `* `.  I'm not sure of a way to get it to export and ignore the heading with default options.  It will probably take some lisp hacking.

Comment: @cm2 Note that I want the heading to be completely ignored, e.g. I do not want the LaTeX export to contain a blank heading such as `\section{}` (which the `* ` method results in).

Comment: Ah, I see.  I suggest editing the question by including the type of LaTeX output you would like to see.

Comment: you should be able to do this using the `ox-extra.el` contrib package -- this is discussed [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html) in the "Ignoring headlines during export" section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no default support for what you are asking. However you can use
a preprocess hook to get a similar output. Here is an example for LaTeX export:

```lisp
;; backend aware export preprocess hook
(defun sa-org-export-preprocess-hook ()
  "My backend aware export preprocess hook."
  (save-excursion
    (when (eq org-export-current-backend 'latex)
      ;; ignoreheading tag for bibliographies and appendices
      (let* ((tag "ignoreheading"))
        (org-map-entries (lambda ()
                           (delete-region (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))
                         (concat ":" tag ":"))))))

(add-hook 'org-export-preprocess-hook 'sa-org-export-preprocess-hook)
```

This is a snippet from my org-mode setup. You can see the original on
[github](https://github.com/suvayu/.emacs.d/blob/master/org-mode-config.el#L234).
The above code will ignore headings tagged with `ignoreheading`, e.g.

```
* Heading 1
* Heading 2                           :ignoreheading:
+ Some text
+ an item
```

gets exported as:

```
\section{Heading 1}
\label{sec-1}

\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item an item
\end{itemize}
```

**Caveat:** There is a known issue with this solution. It
does not work when you try this on the very first headline. I don't
understand why that is the case, hopefully I'll have time someday to
investigate.

**Workaround to caveat:** The above limitation can be
circumvented for LaTeX export by using a line like this after the org
file header:

```
\include{preamble.tex}
```

The `preamble.tex` file can include sections like an abstract or
acknowledgements. However you should note this makes your org file very
closely tied to the export backend. It would become non-trivial to
export the same org file to HTML for example.

**Note:** For a similar setup with the new export framework (Org
8.0 or higher), use the following:

```lisp
(defun sa-ignore-headline (contents backend info)
  "Ignore headlines with tag `ignoreheading'."
  (when (and (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex 'html 'ascii)
          (string-match "\\`.*ignoreheading.*\n"
                (downcase contents)))
    (replace-match "" nil nil contents)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-headline-functions 'sa-ignore-headline)
```

Comment: When I try this in Org-mode 7.6 the heading *and* its content is ignored. I only want the heading to be ignored, not its content.

Comment: Well this has worked for me for over a year, so I would say there is
something wrong locally (also, I tested before posting). If you could give more information, that might help troubleshoot. But SO is probably not an appropriate place for that. I would suggest you post on the mailing list and I can follow up there.

Comment: I tried it with `emacs -q` and it neither worked. I use Emacs 23.3.1.

Comment: Well there is a known issue: the above solution doesn't work when you use it on the very first headline. Other than that I can't find any issues. I am also having difficulty replicating your setup, so I can't test any further. I would again urge you to post on the mailing list.

Comment: It was the issue you mention that prevented it from working for me. I used the example you include in your post to try it. I think you should edit your post and note that to avoid that other be confused too. Is the issue possible to overcome?

Comment: @N.N.Thanks for suggesting to add the above info to the answer. As to your question, I don't know of anyway to get around this. But as a workaround, I use the `\include{sometexfile}` LaTeX directive to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Cool, your answer is better now. Note sure if I understand the workaround. Is the workaround to include some LaTeX file before the first heading?

Comment: There might be reasons to include the workaround in your answer so that others may benefit from it.

Comment: @N.N. Yes I meant using the latex include before the first heading. I'll add this to the answer. Thanks for the suggestion again. :)

Comment: In Latex export, this leaves a stray \label{} command for me (associated with the section that no longer exists), but AFAICT, there is no ill effect from this.

Comment: @jake: this whole ignoreheading business is kind of a kludge ;).  See the mailing list archives from a few months back (search for ignoreheading toc), there are several cases where you can break things.  So a stray `\label` is something we have to live with :).  Edit: when I have some time, I'll update this answer with details.

Comment: `\include{preamble}`will start a new page, which I did not want.  `\input{preamble}`worked better.

Answer (score 6):

Now you can do this easily with `ox-extra`. Add the following to your `init` file:

```
(require 'ox-extra)
(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))
```

Then any headings with `ignore` tag will be ignored, while their content will still be exported.

Comment: You need to include the `titletoc` package: https://orgmode.org/manual/Table-of-contents.html

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple solution for Emacs 24.4.1 and Org-mode 8.2.10 on Debian Jessie that removes tagged headlines before processing, so it removes their structure nodes too, not only the text.

```
;; ignore_heading tag in Org mode, based on the manual and func docs
(defun ignored-headlines-removal (backend)
  "Remove all headlines with tag ignore_heading in the current buffer.
     BACKEND is the export back-end being used, as a symbol."
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda () (delete-region (point) (progn (forward-line) (point))))
   "ignore_heading"))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'ignored-headlines-removal)
```

I didn't make it export backend specific as it does not need to be. I also used the `ignore_heading` tag to make sure the `ignoreheading` tag in beamer export retains its function.

Here is how I discovered it:

1. I looked at the hook documentation in the [Advanced confuguration](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html) section in the Org manual. It contains a hook example that ignores all headlines, almost what I needed, but I had to find a way to delete only headlines with the `ignore_heading` tag.
2. I had a look at the documentation of the `org-map-entries` function (by typing `C-h f org-map-entries RET` in Emacs) and found out its optional second argument `MATCH` is an agenda-style match string that can match tags too.

This experience once again showed me that Emacs truly is an extensible self-documenting editor. RTFM FTW!