# Secret structure in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm wondering I if there's any functionality in org-mode that can make me able to operate with secret structure, that is: structure that I can see when I'm editing but that is treated as if it wasn't there when exporting. It's mainly importing when I export to ascii.

**Example:**

I would like this in the .org file:

```
* Normal heading
** Secret heading 1
Some text 1
** Secret heading 2
Some text 2
** Secret heading 3
Some text 3
```

To be exported to this:

```
Normal heading
--------------
Some text 1
Some text 2
Some text 3
```

What makes the headings secret can be anything like a tag, a property or something else but the secret headings should be foldable.

**Edit:**

Found this solution [(from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295177/is-there-an-equivalent-of-org-modes-b-ignoreheading-for-non-beamer-documents) (I'm using org-mode 7.9.3 f. It doesn't work. Headlines with the :ignoreheading: tag are still displayed:

```
;; backend aware export preprocess hook
(defun sa-org-export-preprocess-hook ()
  "My backend aware export preprocess hook."
  (save-excursion
    (when (eq org-export-current-backend 'latex)
      ;; ignoreheading tag for bibliographies and appendices
      (let* ((tag "ignoreheading"))
        (org-map-entries (lambda ()
                           (delete-region (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))
                         (concat ":" tag ":"))))))

(add-hook 'org-export-preprocess-hook 'sa-org-export-preprocess-hook)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to org-mode 8.2.5h and with that this works:

```
(defun sa-ignore-headline (contents backend info)
  "Ignore headlines with tag `ignoreheading'."
  (when (and (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex 'html 'ascii)
          (string-match "\\`.*ignoreheading.*\n"
                (downcase contents)))
    (replace-match "" nil nil contents)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-headline-functions 'sa-ignore-headline)
```

But only if you don't have the options: #+OPTIONS: `tags:nil`. Guess it's sort of obvious that tags shouldn't be filtered away before a filtering that relies on a certain tag is invoked - but that bugged me for quite some time.

Note: when exporting to ascii the headline underlining will remain without the headline, so you need this setting too:

```
(setq org-ascii-underline (quote ((ascii) (latin1) (utf-8))))
```

... to remove headlines all together.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `EXCLUDE_TAGS` property and tag certain sections, then export with `org-export-exclude-tags`. E.g:

```
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport

* Public Section

* Secret Section :noexport:
```

Documentation [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings).

Comment: The EXCLUDE_TAGS excludes both the heading and the content of that heading. I'm interested in excluding only the heading.

Comment: @MajorBriggs Ah, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is addressed [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17677/8541) -- and here's the answer (repeated):

1. Add the following to your `.emacs` file:

   ```
   (require 'ox-extra)
   (ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))
   ```
2. Use the `ignore` tag on headlines you'd like to have ignored (while not ignoring their content)

Comment: This seems to work and seems simpler than the accepted solution.

Comment: The require step does not work, gives me a file-missing error. I am using orgmode 9.1.9, and I cannot find this file anywhere. I'm on a Mac also. Any advice?

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé See the info in the linked answer on adding the org-mode ELPA repository.

Answer (score 1):

In the [linked question about the ignoreheading tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295177/is-there-an-equivalent-of-org-modes-b-ignoreheading-for-non-beamer-documents?lq=1) I posted a working, [simpler org-export-before-parsing-hook solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588450/4779220) for Org 8.2.10 in Emacs 24.1.1.

It is based on the documentation of the `org-map-entries` function which also states that it wraps it in `save-recursion` automatically. It is simpler than using `concat` because the second argument to `org-map-entries` is an agenda-style match string.

Answer (score 1):

While trying to solve the same problem I found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27827/omitting-headlines-when-exporting-from-org-mode-to-latex) thread describing how to extend `ox-extra.el` using a `notignore` tag. This method does not export **any** headings unless explicitly tagged `notignore`. Content of the heading are exported normally.

For most of my documents the `notignore` approach is more useful than the 'ignore' approach because the majority of headings are 'secret structure' not intended for export.

Presently I have `notignore-headlines` activated in my init.el file. Can anyone suggest a way to activate this on a per document basis.